# How to delete programatically empty sections in Power Point

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a very large Power Point file that I have to break up in 10 sub files. I moved my slides to new empty presentations and all is good except that the sections stayed there and I have to delete them one by one.

Is there a way to delete empty sections quickly?

Answer (score 2):

This Function should work:

```
Function DeleteEmptySections(oPres As Presentation)
  Dim lSP As Long
  With oPres.SectionProperties
    For lSP = .Count To 1 Step -1
        If .SlidesCount(lSP) = 0 Then
            .Delete lSP, True
        End If
    Next
  End With
End Function
```

or use a Sub for this to test on ActivePresentation:

```
Sub DeleteEmptySectionInCurPres()
   Call DeleteEmptySections(ActivePresentation)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not substantially different than the existing answer to this question... you've literally offered nothing new in the way of explanation, or method in this answer.

Comment: My code is running. The existing answer by Jamie not. See: lSP variable is not used. or make a diff with my code ;-) But you're right the idea is the same.

Comment: Glad to read! You're welcome. Maybe you can mark this answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SectionProperties collection to loop backwards to delete any section that has no slides:

```
Sub DeleteEmptySections()
  Dim lSP as Long
  With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
    For lSP = .Count to 1 Step -1
      If .SlidesCount = 0 Then .Delete
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a correction to the above code

```
Sub DeleteEmptySections()
    Dim lSP As Long
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        For lSP = .Count To 1 Step -1
            If .SlidesCount(lSP) = 0 Then .Delete lSP, True
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should cite the guy that wrote the code you are providing a fix; when they get voted they will, possible, change places, and **up** or **second** will have no meaning. And explaining what was wrong and how it get fixed will be nice too, increasing odds that you be upvoted.